# UIAutomation iOS - delete a table cell

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am working on deleting a table cell. I thought it will be done this way.

```
var myCell = cells["abc"];
var deleteSwitch = myCell.switches()[0];
deleteSwitch.tap();
```

but, when I tried to logElementTree in myCell, it did not show me any UIASwitch.
It displayed UIAStaticText which has the name of the cell and toggle button in order to enter edit mode. When I record my actions to capture script, I tried o tap on delete button to delete text and it recorded as a tap on that cell but not on switch/button.

Please let me know how to delete a cell.

Answer (score 0):

In order for any element to appear in element tree, you should have accessibility enabled on that element. Do you have accessibility enabled on UISwitch inside iOS code? If your switch name in iOS code is say 'mySwitch', then try doing:

```
[mySwitch setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
```